# Can't find a launcher for LMMS

Tags: 11.04

Since upgrading to Natty I can't find LMMS (Linux Multimedia Studio).

I've attempted to reinstall from terminal, but it tells me it is already the latest version.

Comment: There is a bug report on Launchpad regarding this issue. People affected by it should say so in the bug report by clicking "does this affect you?" so it is more likely to be looked at.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure why this didn't show up in installed applications under Natty (hopefully someone can explain that to me).

I followed the instructions in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=907888):

- Right click on the desktop and choose "Create Launcher"
- Enter anything you would like for the name (in this case I chose LMMS)
- Enter lmms in the Command field
- Click OK; This will create a Launcher on the desktop
- Drag the icon onto the side bar launcher

I guess there is probably a way to create this shortcut in an easier way without creating a Launcher on the desktop, but I can't see how to do it. If you right click on the side bar launcher there is no context menu.

Answer (score 1):

To show up correctly in the dash (or in the menu for older versions of Ubuntu), a program has to install a [*desktop file*](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) . The lmms sources contain such a desktop file, but for some reason it is not installed as part of the lmms package (which should actually be reported as a bug against the lmms package). 
You can easily add the desktop file yourself, copy&paste the following in a text editor (this is the desktop file that should have been installed):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Linux MultiMedia Studio
GenericName=music production suite
GenericName[ca]=Programari de producció musical
GenericName[de]=Software zur Musik-Produktion
Comment=easy music production for everyone!
Comment[ca]=Producció fàcil de música per a tothom!
Icon=lmms
Exec=lmms
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;AudioVideo;Audio;Midi;
MimeType=application/x-lmms-project;
```

Save the file as `lmms.desktop` in the directory `~/.local/share/applications` (note the dot in the beginning of the path, it is a hidden directory in your home directory. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or right click in the save file dialog to switch the display of hidden files and directories).

lmms should now appear in the dash as all other applications do. Once it is started, you can right click at the icon in the launcher and select “keep in launcher”.

Comment: Suggested edit that has been rejected:  You could also change the "Icon" Line to point to a better (higher res) png image that you have downloaded. The default one is quite ugly. e.g. Icon=/home/(your-user-name)/Pictures/icons/lmms.png